# JS API - onDrawEnd firing twice

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, events, map-drawing

I have a simple editing application with the following code:

```
startEditing : function(template) {

    var drawingTool = template.template.drawingTool;

    switch(drawingTool) {
        case FeatureTemplate.TOOL_POINT:
            drawingTool = Draw.POINT;
            break;
        }

    on(this.drawingToolbar, "draw-end", lang.hitch(this, this.createFeature, template));

    this.drawingToolbar.activate(drawingTool);
}
```

and

```
createFeature : function(template, evt) {

    var featureLayer = template.featureLayer;
    template = template.template;

    var prototype = template.prototype;

    var geometry = evt.geometry;

    var graphic = new Graphic(prototype.toJson());
    graphic.setGeometry(geometry);

    this.initAttributes(graphic, featureLayer).then(function() {

        var features = [graphic];

        featureLayer.applyEdits(features).then(function(addResults) {
            var objectIds = array.map(addResults, function(addResult) {
                return addResult.objectId;
            });

            var q = new Query();
            q.objectIds = objectIds;

            featureLayer.selectFeatures(q).then(function(features) {
                main.openForm(features);
            });
        });

    });

}
```

Using a point tool with the drawing toolbar, I am finding that when I click a point on the map, the createFeature function is called twice resulting in 2 features being created with the same geometry. How can I stop the draw toolbar from creating 2 features?

Comment: I'd first try adding a breakpoint to createFeature and then inspecting the call stack when it's hit. If you persevere with the cryptically-named functions you might be able to discover what's triggering each call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason this was happening is because it is possible for the `startEditing` function to be called multiple times as this function is called anytime the `templatePicker` selection changes.  Every time the `startEditing` function is called, it creates a new `onDrawEnd` handler.

There is also a `stopEditing` function that is called when the `templatePicker` selection changes and the selection is `null`.  My solution was to add some code that allows me to remove the `onDrawEnd` handler inside the `stopEditing` function.